# Pre-load Tensorflow/Keras in Docker image

Tags: docker, tensorflow, keras

My goal is to do a prediction using pre-trained model in safe docker environment as quickly as possible.

I have built a docker container including Miniconda, Tensorflow-GPU and Keras, which starts in 0.5s or so (all good).  But initialisation of Tensorflow at the start of the prediction script takes multiple additional seconds. Since the model is untrusted, I wanted to run every single prediction in separate docker.

Is there a way to build docker image with Tensorflow initialised and "ready-to-go"?

Comment: Stopped container = stopped process. If it takes some time to start there’s nothing you can do. It’s not as if a container is a vm you can take snapshot of.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://medium.com/@kaibrooks/creating-a-neural-network-from-the-ground-up-for-classifying-your-own-images-in-keras-tensorflow-91e57d480c24